# Create new matrix with all non-zero elements set to ones (julia)

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra

I would like an efficient (vectorized) way of manipulating a matrix in julia into a new matrix where all non-zero elements are ones in the new matrix.

For example, I would like this matrix

```
0 3 6 8 0
7 0 2 0 1
0 4 9 1 0
```

to become

```
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: Efficient does not equal vectorized in Julia. Loops are fast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest is to convert this matrix to a `BitMatrix` matrix like this:

```
julia> x = [0 3 6 8 0
            7 0 2 0 1
            0 4 9 1 0]
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  3  6  8  0
 7  0  2  0  1
 0  4  9  1  0

julia> x .!= 0
3×5 BitMatrix:
 0  1  1  1  0
 1  0  1  0  1
 0  1  1  1  0
```

If you want the matrix to contain `Int` values then you can do:

```
julia> Int.(x .!= 0)
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1  1  1  0
 1  0  1  0  1
 0  1  1  1  0
```

Finally if your `0` values have mixed types and you would want to preserve them "as is" then you can do:

```
julia> x = Real[0   3 6 8 UInt8(0)
                7   0 2 0 1
                0.0 4 9 1 0]
3×5 Matrix{Real}:
 0    3  6  8  0x00
 7    0  2  0     1
 0.0  4  9  1     0

julia> @. ifelse(iszero(x), x, 1)
3×5 Matrix{Real}:
 0    1  1  1  0x00
 1    0  1  0     1
 0.0  1  1  1     0
```

Apart from broadcasting you could use comprehension which also should be fast. Eg.

```
julia> [v == 0 ? v : 1 for v in x]
3×5 Matrix{Real}:
 0    1  1  1  0x00
 1    0  1  0     1
 0.0  1  1  1     0
```

or e.g.

```
julia> [ifelse(v == 0, 0, 1) for v in x]
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1  1  1  0
 1  0  1  0  1
 0  1  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried x > 0 but I see that I missed the dot operator (x .> 0).

Answer (score 3):

An alternative not yet mentioned is to use `map`:

```
julia> x = [0 3 6 8 0
            7 0 2 0 1
            0 4 9 1 0]
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  3  6  8  0
 7  0  2  0  1
 0  4  9  1  0

julia> map(!=(0), x)
3×5 Matrix{Bool}:
 0  1  1  1  0
 1  0  1  0  1
 0  1  1  1  0
```

Note that `!=(0)` is equivalent to `y -> y != 0`.

As another answer shows, the result of broadcasting a Bool-valued function is a `BitMatrix`. Using `map` avoids this.

If you want a solution that produces "0" and "1" of the same type as the input:

```
julia> map(y -> ifelse(y == zero(y), one(y), zero(y)), x)
3×5 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  0  0  0  1
 0  1  0  1  0
 1  0  0  0  1

julia> map(y -> ifelse(y == zero(y), one(y), zero(y)), Float64.(x))
3×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Yes, `map` is another option. The choice between `Matrix{Bool}` and `BitMatrix` depends on the use case, but AFAICT `BitMatrix` is usually preferred as it has a much smaller memory footprint. Note that comprehension like `[v != 0 for v in x]` would also produce a `Matrix{Bool}`.

Comment: `BitMatrix` could be slower in some cases, and unlike `Matrix{Bool}`, might introduce race conditions if multiple threads are writing into the array.

Comment: Exactly - this is what I meant by saying that it depends on the use case.